# How can I compare struct data and interface data in Golang?

Tags: go, data-structures

I am trying to create a generic Binary Tree in Golang. How can I compare data from an interface and input data in the code? Here is an example of what I am trying to do. The comparison that is giving me trouble is this

```
 } else if cur.data < data {
```

-

```golang
package DSAA

type TreeNode struct {
    data interface{}
    right *TreeNode
    left *TreeNode
}

type BinarySearchTree struct {
    root *TreeNode
}

func BSTCreate() *BinarySearchTree {
    return &BinarySearchTree{nil}
}

func (b *BinarySearchTree) Insert(cur TreeNode, data interface{}) *BinarySearchTree {
    if &cur == nil {
        cur := &TreeNode{data, nil, nil}
    } else if cur.data < data {
        b = b.Insert(*cur.left, data)
    } else {
        b = b.Insert(*cur.right, data)
    }
    return b
}
```

Comment: what is in your data, in runtime?

Comment: Check whether the runtime types are the same before doing this using reflect.TypeOf()

Comment: I plan on it being a string or an integer. Similar to how you can use <T> in java and .compareTo()

Comment: Go is not Java. You might get some inspiration from https://github.com/emirpasic/gods/blob/master/trees/btree/btree.go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some options:
1-  Using runtime type switch:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Less(1, 2))       // true
    fmt.Println(Less("AB", "AC")) // true
}

func Less(a, b interface{}) bool {
    switch v := a.(type) {
    case int:
        w := b.(int)
        return v < w
    case string:
        w := b.(string)
        return v < w

    }
    return false
}
```

then replace `} else if cur.data < data {` with 
`} else if Less(cur.data , data) {`

---

2- Using `Comparer interface`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Comparer interface {
    // Less reports whether the element  is less than b
    Less(b interface{}) bool
}

func main() {
    a, b := Int(1), Int(2)
    fmt.Println(a.Less(b)) // true

    c, d := St("A"), St("B")
    fmt.Println(c.Less(d)) // true
}

type Int int

func (t Int) Less(b interface{}) bool {
    if v, ok := b.(Int); ok {
        return int(t) < int(v)
    }
    return false
}

type St string

func (t St) Less(b interface{}) bool {
    if v, ok := b.(St); ok {
        return string(t) < string(v)
    }
    return false
}
```

---

3- Using `reflect`

Comment: Could you give me a quick example of how you would use Less in this context?